# A function to read CSV data from a file into memory

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to create a function that reads a csv file into a memory in a list form. When I run my code, it gives me this error message ("string indices must be integers"). Were am I getting it wrong.
Below is the code. Thanks for your help

```
# create the empty set to carry the values of the columns

Hydropower_heading = []
Solar_heading = []
Wind_heading = []
Other_heading = []

def my_task1_file(filename):                              # defines the function "my_task1_file"
    with open(filename,'r') as myNew_file:                # opens and read the file
        for my_file in myNew_file.readlines():            # loops through the file

# read the values into the empty set created
            Hydropower_heading.append(my_file['Hydropower'])
            Solar_heading.append(my_file['Solar'])
            Wind_heading.append(my_file['Wind'])
            Other_heading.append(my_file['Other'])

#Hydropower_heading = int(Hydropower)
#Solar_heading = int(Solar)
#Wind_heading = int(Wind)
#Other_heading = int(Other)            
            
my_task1_file('task1.csv')                                # calls the csv file into the function 

# print the Heading and the column values in a row form
print('Hydropower: ', Hydropower_heading)
print('Solar: ', Solar_heading)
print('Wind: ', Wind_heading)
print('Other: ', Other_heading)
```

Comment: readLines will give you an iterable with each line as a string. You are trying to use it like a dictionary. Take a look at built-in `csv` library for proper parsing of csv files.
https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html

Answer (score 3):

We can read CSV files by the column using [csv.DictReader method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader).

**Code: (`code.py`)**

```
import csv


def my_task1_file(filename):  # defines the function "my_task1_file"
    Hydropower_heading = []
    Solar_heading = []
    Wind_heading = []
    Other_heading = []
    with open(filename, newline='\n') as csvfile:
        reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
        for row in reader:
            # read the values into the empty set created
            Hydropower_heading.append(row['Hydropower'])
            Solar_heading.append(row['Solar'])
            Wind_heading.append(row['Wind'])
            Other_heading.append(row['Other'])
    return Hydropower_heading, Solar_heading, Wind_heading, Other_heading

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Hydropower_heading, Solar_heading, Wind_heading, Other_heading = my_task1_file('task1.csv')

    # print the Heading and the column values in a row form
    print('Hydropower: ', Hydropower_heading)
    print('Solar: ', Solar_heading)
    print('Wind: ', Wind_heading)
    print('Other: ', Other_heading)
```

`task1.csv`:

```
Hydropower,Solar,Wind,Other
5,6,3,8
6,8,5,12
3,6,9,7
```

**Output:**

```
Hydropower:  ['5', '6', '3']
Solar:  ['6', '8', '6']
Wind:  ['3', '5', '9']
Other:  ['8', '12', '7']
```

**Explanation:**

- The [`__main__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/__main__.html) condition will check if the file is running directly. If the file is being run directly by using `python code.py`, it will execute this portion. Otherwise if we import `code.py` from another python file, this portion will not be executed.
- You can remove the `__main__` block as necessary like below. But it is a good practice to separate the methods from executing while importing one python file from another using the `__main__`  block. Let me know if it clears your confusion.

`code.py` (without `__main__`):

```
import csv


def my_task1_file(filename):  # defines the function "my_task1_file"
    Hydropower_heading = []
    Solar_heading = []
    Wind_heading = []
    Other_heading = []
    with open(filename, newline='\n') as csvfile:
        reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
        for row in reader:
            # read the values into the empty set created
            Hydropower_heading.append(row['Hydropower'])
            Solar_heading.append(row['Solar'])
            Wind_heading.append(row['Wind'])
            Other_heading.append(row['Other'])
    return Hydropower_heading, Solar_heading, Wind_heading, Other_heading

Hydropower_heading, Solar_heading, Wind_heading, Other_heading = my_task1_file('task1.csv')

print('Hydropower: ', Hydropower_heading)
print('Solar: ', Solar_heading)
print('Wind: ', Wind_heading)
print('Other: ', Other_heading)
```

**References:**

- [csv.DictReader method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader)
- [`__main__` documentation from Python website](https://docs.python.org/3/library/__main__.html)

Comment: if __name__ == "__main__": what will replace this comment because I'm a bit confused here, please

Comment: I gone through the documentation. I am not supposed to use any python modules to write my codes. Therefore, is there anyway around it that I can get it to run because I am still getting an error message. Thank you

Comment: Hi @EugeneGyimah ! I have updated the answer to explain the `__main__` block. Let me know if it clears your confusions.

Comment: Sorry, you code contains import csv which is not a requirement of my work. Is there a way I can go around it? Your code works perfectly but I don't want to use any python module. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Since the error is "string indices must be integers", you must be using a data type that cannot take in a string value as an index. In this segment of your code...

```
for my_file in myNew_file.readlines():
     
     Hydropower_heading.append(my_file['Hydropower'])
     Solar_heading.append(my_file['Solar'])
     Wind_heading.append(my_file['Wind'])
     Other_heading.append(my_file['Other'])
```

... you are using "Hydropower", "Solar", "Wind", and "Other" as index values, which cannot be valid index values of my_file, which, I assume, is a string data type since you are reading the file `myNew_file`. If you change these values to integers as is appropriate, then the error should not appear anymore.

Comment: How is it done, please?

Comment: Assuming that each line of your csv has four values separated by commas in the format of `num0,num1,num2,num3` and if you want the first column to correspond to "Hydropower", the second column to "Solar", etc., then you could probably do this: replace `my_file['Hydropower']` with `my_file[0]`; replace `my_file['Solar']` with `my_file[1]`; replace `my_file['Wind']` with `my_file[2]`; and replace `my_file['Other']` with `my_file[3]`. Let me know if this works.

Comment: It brings out only the first digits of the columns. For instance, if the value is 2.305, it returns 2, then the next value

Comment: Are each of the values in the csv columns supposed to be integers or floats? It seems that the problem is that you have a float that has its type changed into an integer. For example, `int(2.305)` would evaluate to `2` as you have explained, and so on.